# Convert Nginx rewrite from "if" to "try_files"

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following NGINX rewrite rule which works great for a PHP script installed in a subfolder:

```
location /subfolder/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/subfolder/(.*) /subfolder/index.php?do=/$1;
  }
}
```

but Nginx wiki says using "if" is evil http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil so I tried the following

```
location /subfolder/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /subfolder/index.php?$args;
}
```

but it doesn't work to replace the one above, although it works for WordPress and most of the PHP scripts. If there a way to translate it to use "try_files"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to do the rewrite only if the file doesn't exist, use it as a named location for the fall back in `try_files`

```
location /subfolder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/subfolder/(.*) /subfolder/index.php?do=/$1;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work and Nginx won't start with the following error message: [emerg] unknown directive "$uri" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2252

Comment: And it was referring to the following line: $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

Comment: Adding try_files also didn't help: try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite; it generates the following error: unknown directive "@rewrite" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2254

Comment: what nginx version do you have ?, and yea i forgot to write `try_files`

Comment: My Nginx version is 1.0.10

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've upgraded to Nginx 1.4.x. I had to add "location" in front of "@rewrite {" line and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, idk why but apparently I was having a slow moment, 2 mistakes in the same answer, glad you figured it out, and thanks @VBart for fixing the answer.

Comment: bro you solved my great pain because i was living nginx just because i doesn't find any better way for rewriting urls .
Can you suggest a way to rewrite only non integral requests  like avoiding  ( /subfolder/1 or /subfolder/2 or /subfolder/3 )