# Convert .htaccess rewrite rule to PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pantheon

I have a WordPress site running on Pantheon, which uses nginx. Rewrite rules in the .htaccess files are ignored, so they need to be placed in wp-config.php instead. My regex skills are more or less nonexistent, and I need to convert these rewrite rules to PHP:

```
rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2" last;
rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml\.gz$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;zip=true" last;
rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true" last;
rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html.gz$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true;zip=true" last;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Aren't you still going to be using the regex in PHP?

Comment: Yes, but there are minor syntactical differences for regex in PHP. Also, being only moderately familiar with mod_rewrite rules, I can see there are aspects to these rules that also need conversion to PHP, besides just the regex.

Comment: The only difference I think you'll need is the delimiters. They both are using PCRE so it should perform the same. You can set the `$_GET`s in the code and then include the `index.php` so it loads the expected content..or you could use a `header` if it is suppose to redirect.

Comment: Thanks! What about the "last" after each rewrite rule? How should this get handled in php?

Comment: I've never seen the `last` like that before. I've seen `[L]` and if that is the same you should be able to just use a series of conditionals for this. `if(preg_match)..}elseif(preg_match){...``

Comment: I have also created a new pantheon tag for better discoverability and attached it to a number of related question.

Comment: @joakland was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments.

First regarding the `last` flag, straight from the [Apache documentation on rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

> The `[L|last]` flag causes `mod_rewrite` to stop processing the rule
>   set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further
>   rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl,
>   or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Here are some more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800150/8291949) on `last`.

Therefore, the pattern you would have to implement should look like a [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or a series of [`if-elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)s.

However, the Nginx wiki says [using "if" is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). It is suggested useing [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files) instead.

See also/Further references:

- Pantheon Docs: [Using PHP as an htaccess Alternative](https://pantheon.io/docs/htaccess/)
- [Pantheon Docs](https://pantheon.io/docs/domains/): See more redirect scenarios
- [Convert Nginx rewrite from "if" to "try_files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011583/convert-nginx-rewrite-from-if-to-try-files)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Uses curl to proxy to a different URL path. Works with Drupal and Wordpress.  https://github.com/mpaladino/pantheon-htaccess-rewrites